# How do I make it so I have a smoother NPC pathfinding script in Roblox

Tags: lua, roblox

I am trying to make a game where you fight enemy NPCs and the NPCs need a pathfinding script so they can get to the player and attack the player and I found a working pathfinding script but there is 1 problem, sometimes, it will start walking back for a second while chasing the player, but i want it so it doesn't do that, this is what happens when I use it:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_3dfBo1v0UVv25HngVi6EyqWiMbQ8pG8/view?usp=sharing

this is my script for the pathfinding:

```
local npc = script.Parent
local human = npc.Humanoid

local PFS = game:GetService("PathfindingService")
local RUNSERVICE = game:GetService("RunService")

npc.PrimaryPart:SetNetworkOwner(nil)

local function findTarget()
    local players = game:GetService("Players"):GetPlayers()
    local nearesttarget
    local maxDistance = 5000

    for i,player in pairs(players) do
        if player.Character then
            local target = player.Character
            local distance = (npc.HumanoidRootPart.Position - target:WaitForChild("HumanoidRootPart").Position).Magnitude

            if distance < maxDistance then
                nearesttarget = target
                maxDistance = distance
            end

        end
    end
    return nearesttarget
end

local function getPath(destination)
    local path = PFS:CreatePath()
    path:ComputeAsync(npc.HumanoidRootPart.Position, destination)
    return path
end

local function pathFindTo(destination)
    local path = getPath(destination)
    local target = findTarget()

    if target and target.Humanoid.Health > 0 then
        for i,waypoint in pairs(path:GetWaypoints()) do
            if waypoint.Action == Enum.PathWaypointAction.Jump then
                human.Jump = false
            end
            human:MoveTo(waypoint.Position)
            human.MoveToFinished:Wait()
        end
    end
end

RUNSERVICE.Heartbeat:Connect(function()
    local target = findTarget()
    
    if target then
        pathFindTo(target:WaitForChild("HumanoidRootPart").Position + (target:WaitForChild("HumanoidRootPart").Velocity.Unit * 7))
    end
end)
```

and this is a screenshot of my hierarchy:
[Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBSow.png)